# Cannot separate code when using DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, solid-principles

I always try to separate my code as much as possible. I'm fairly new to ASP.NET Core but the code principles and software design patterns are the same in all languages, however, when using entity-framework, there's something that bothers me, or that I don't know how to deal with.

In my application, I have users, which of course are created when registering. The users can add specific items to their inventory and request items to share from other users.

So I have a `SharingRequests` table, which has information such as `UserBorrowerId`, `UserLenderId`, `InventoryItemId` etc.

When I now want to create a sharing request and assign the user to it, I have to it all in the same context. For example, if I do this

```
MethodA: 
await using (var context = new DbContext())
{
    User user = context
        .Users
        .Where(u => u.Id == userId)
        .First();
}

methodB(user);
```

```
MethodB:
await using (var context = new DbContext())
{
    Item item = context
        .Items
        .Where(i => i.Id == itemId)
        .First();

    SharingRequest sharingRequest = new SharingRequest();
    sharingRequest.Item = item;
    sharingRequest.User = user;

    context.SharingRequests.AddAsync(sharingRequest);
    context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I get the error that the user already exists in the database and it cannot create a new entry because of the duplicate key.

After googling this issue, I found that this is, because I have multiple database contexts, and the 2nd context doesn't know about the first one.

However, this means, that EVERY entity that I need, which needs to be loaded etc. all needs to IN ONE `await using (var context = new DbContext())`

I fail to see how I can separate my code logically with this restriction. This forces me to have a method that does way too much things.

Why isn't it possible to have a method to get the user, another one to build the sharing request (another one to do the validation) etc.?

Am I missing sth. completely here? I can't imagine that this is the way applications have to be build because of the duplicate key problem.

Comment: You need to use dependency injection. `Services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(...)` then inject `DbContext` in the classes containing the various methods

Comment: And when I use DI for the Context, then I won't have to put everyting in ONE db context await statement?

Comment: No. The DI system will dispose it for you

Comment: Thanks. Used DI and now I can separate it without any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are missing alot, firstly inject db context into the controller constructor and register in startup.cs, secondly have a method that gets the user and returns it. It has nothing to do with entity framework, just knowing how code works and post your actually method signatures.

How do you have multiple contexts? they both look exactly the same. Have you heard of unit of work pattern?

The error has nothing to do with db context, you are trying to create a user that already exists.

Do not use first always use firstordefault. You should check out codewithmosh he has a course on entity framework. Do not confuse clean code with functional code. You have to learn the basics of ef to apply clean code rules to it. Follow the path get it working, then clean it up.

Comment: Hi. I actually already have the DBContext registered for DI, but only used it in classes, not in the `Controller`. I also have a `DBContextFactory` so I can mock it in unit tests. However, I don't see how I'm trying to create a user that already exists, since the only thing I'm adding to the context is `context.SharingRequests.AddAsync(sharingRequest);` That's what confuses me. Thanks I will check him out.

Comment: Okay, I actually used the DI approach and now I can seperate it. I think the problem was that I always used `new DbContext` instead of using the DI approach. That was my bad, I thought it has to be done that way. Now that I've changed it, I can seperate it without any problems. 

Thank you!

Comment: No worries. Use the repository pattern if you want to mock and unit test. But you should be testing controller logic, not just your repositories and use an in memory database.Make a seperate repository for each entity instead of generic repository as i have that mistake in the past, make it easier to debug.

Comment: Yes, I have already have repositories for InventoryItem and Inventory, others (users, sharing etc.) to come. The controllers I would test with functional/integration tests with an sqlite db (or e2e tests) with endtest.io (but for that in the future). :) Thanks for the exchange!

Comment: You can use an in memory datatabse that replicates sql server or what ever db you are using, using sql lite is not testing it correctly, its using a difference type of database against a different type of database. SQL lite does not have all the capabilities of the bigger databases, its not like for like test.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Wasn't logged in. If you check this article https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/testing/in-memory, it actually states `SQLite is a relational provider and can also use in-memory databases. Consider using this for testing to more closely match common relational database behaviors. This is covered in Using SQLite to test an EF Core application.`